# Getting the children, grand children in hierarchical structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hierarchical-data, ltree

I am working with hierarchical data model with rails and gem called ltree_hierarchy(https://github.com/cfabianski/ltree_hierarchy). In that each node will have a parent id(which is an immediate parent of the current node).

```
         1

     2       3

 4    5    6    7
```

the hierarchical structure is achieved using ltree extension of postgres. and in the gem ltree_hierarchy, the parent and path will be saved.

```
node       parent        path

  1         NULL         1

  2          1           1.2

  3          1           1.3

  4          2           1.2.4

  5          2           1.2.5

  6          3           1.3.6

  7          3           1.3.7
```

I can get the sibling, parent and children using the parent_id of the node. something like,

```
select * from table where parent_id = 1; # for getting the children of a node 1

select * from table where parent_id = 1 and id !=2; # for getting the sibling of a node 2
```

Is there any suggestion to get the children and grand children of a node in a single query?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Just use the library to get the children and their grand children.

Comment: I checked it.  But there is no method to get the grandchildren.  What I want is to get a nodes at some depth of the subtree.  What I mentioned is to get the children and grand children of the node which is basically 2 level from any of the nodes.

Comment: It's right there in the docs: `root.children.first.children.first # => subchild`

Comment: I can get grandchild of any of the children of the desired node with the method you specified. But I can't get all the children of children. Anyways thanks for the response.

Comment: `first` is just shorthand for fist element in the list. perhaps `descendants` would be of use too

Comment: But descendants will list all the nodes under a root of subtree. But I am not clear how to get the nodes with some level(say 2). Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The result might be something to do with `limit` right?

Comment: Root is where you want to start off. So you could fetch any node and then call `descendants`. Or you could do `root.first.descendants`. Or `root.last.children.first.descendants`. Etc, etc. Well, that's what I assume at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using postgres' `LTREE` underneath - you can query it directly (see [postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html)) like

```
 select * from table where path ~ '1234.*{1,2}'
```

(here `1234` is id of parent, and `*{1,2}` instructs to match at least one level and at most 2)